# pushViewController lead to black screen, NO STORYBOARD

Tags: ios, objective-c

I see all the other solutions and nothing works for me. When I initiate the application, it works fine, but when I click a table item and push a ViewController, the screen goes black, and keeps black forever. Here is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    ToDoItemViewController *itemViewController = [[ToDoItemViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ToDoItemViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    ToDoItem *itemSelected = [[self toDoItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    itemViewController.toDoItem = itemSelected;
    itemViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:itemViewController animated:YES];
}
```

The name of the Nib is ok, and the ToDoItemViewController:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Remember, I DON'T USE STORYBOARDS and I want to keep that

**EDIT**

Here is how I launch my first ViewController

```
ListadoViewController *listadoViewController = [[ListadoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListadoViewController" bundle:nil];
        CustomNavigationController *navCtrl = [[CustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:listadoViewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navCtrl;
```

Comment: but your initial viewcontroller is embedded in a navigationcontroller?

Comment: Just before your push, what do you see if you add something like `NSLog(@"Nav controller %@, item controller %@", self.navigationController, itemViewController);`?

Comment: To-Do List con Login[4067:90065] Nav controller <CustomNavigationController: 0x7a25c000>, item controller <ToDoItemViewController: 0x7b04e2f0>

Comment: Have you remembered to call [super viewDidLoad] in your pushed controller? Is that being called? Same for viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. The problem was that I implement the method "loadView", but I didn't know that that method is implemented by iOS, so I was not calling the super and it wasn't drawing anything.

Thanks all for your responses.

Comment: Say what? The documentation says not to call super if you implement `loadView`. You shouldn't even be implementing `loadView` since you're loading the view from a xib file.

Comment: No, I didn't know that `loadView` was a method of ViewController, I was not calling it intetionally